# Problem with jQuery when using chrome extensions popup

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome-extension, popup, chrome-extension-manifest-v3

There is a website and there is a button that has the disabled tag. I'm trying to write a popup extension where there is a button, by clicking on which this tag should be removed.

```
//manifest.json
{
  "name": "Remove",
  "version": "1.0",
  "manifest_version": 3,
  "permissions": ["activeTab", "scripting"],
  "action": {
    "default_popup": "popup/popup.html",
    "default_icon": {
      "128": "/images/logo_128.png"
    }
  },
  "icons": {
    "128": "/images/logo_128.png"
  }
}
```

[image][image]

When I click button in popup I get this and no more:

[image]

What can I do?

I try changing `$` to `JQuery`. Load different versions.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The injected function can't reference any code or function or variable or library outside of it. The reason is that `executeScript` simply takes the source code of the function as a text string and internally injects this string into the web page as a content script, so the only things it has access to are the things in the content script context.

Solutions:

1. inject jquery first in another executeScript using `files` instead of `function` - use only when injecting complex code.
2. switch to native DOM methods - preferred for simple cases like this one.

Comment: chrome.tabs.executeScript(null, { 
 file: "jquery-3.6.0.min.js"
});
chrome.tabs.executeScript(null, { 
 file: "contentscript.js"
});

Comment: @11 where do I call it?